# HTML to PDF with CMYK and Spot Colour functionality

Tags: php, html, pdf

I am working with a client who would like an end-user on a website to select a colour and font to be applied to a sticker. I then need to generate a print-ready PDF to send directly to the printer. It needs to be in the CMYK colour space and must include a dieline in a spot-colour.

For the life of me, I can't find a HTML to PDF library that has this functionality. Does anyone know of one?

Comment: [mpdf](https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf) supports spot colours and CMYK colour space.

Comment: Thanks, @cOle2. That's a great help. I've checked it out and it looks like that could be the way to go. Would you happen to know how I could go about flattening the pdf / outlining the fonts prior to sending it to the printer? I don't see anything in the docs. Perhaps I need to run it through something else after mpdf?

Comment: I don't think mpdf can outline/flatten. Ghostscript should be able to outline. I know PDFtk can flatten, maybe it can do the outline too.